# Onomatopoeic words with repeated first syllable

Tags: onomatopoeia

I've come across a small number of onomatopoeic words whose first syllables repeat:

borborygmus

tintinnabulation

ululation

I was wondering is there is a word describing such words and if any of your have come across more examples. Thanks!

Edit: Added

murmuration

susurration

Answer (score 2):

I will take a stab at converting my comment into an answer, since there are no others.  I do not think there is a single word combining both concepts, but there are words for each concept independently.

You clearly already know the first, for words which imitate a sound the word describes-  onomatopoeia.  [From M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onomatopoeia):

> : the naming of a thing or action by a vocal imitation of the sound associated with it (such as buzz, hiss)

The other part, where a syllable or partial syllable is repeated within a word, is called reduplication.  [Again M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reduplication):

> 1: an act or instance of doubling or reiterating
>
> 2a : an often grammatically functional repetition of a radical element or a part of it occurring usually at the beginning of a word and often accompanied by change of the radical vowel
>
> b(1) : a word or form produced by reduplication
>
> (2) : the repeated element in such a word or form

From [this blog](http://blog.writeathome.com/index.php/2013/05/reduplication/) I get a list of several example of reduplication, including flim-flam, riff-raff, and bye-bye.

Within this same list, I find a few more that might fit both criteria of onomatopoeia and reduplication: knock-knock, clip-clop (of a horse's hooves), tom-tom, and a few others possibly on the fringe, such as choo-choo (usually a  name for a train, not the sound of a train, but originating from that sound).  In other words, yes, there are examples beside borborygmus and tintinnabula.

As for describing these words with as short of a phrase as possible, I might tongue-in-cheek suggest reduplicated onomatopoeia or onomatopoetic reduplication.  Or just call them "words that combine onomatopoeia with reduplication," though that is admittedly a mouthful.  How you ultimately would do this depends a bit on context which I do not know.